# listen called on socket more than once -- expected behavior?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I noticed something odd while working with a simple C-based server
program on my Linux (4.10.3) system. I accidentally ended up calling
`listen()` twice on a socket (from the server process) I had
called `bind()` on earlier. I noticed that both the listen calls
succeeded without any errors. In fact, it doesn't seem to matter how many
calls to listen I make, all calls to listen succeed.

I was expecting all the calls to listen after the first one to fail
with `EADDRINUSE`. Am I missing something? Linux/POSIX man pages don't
seem to say anything about this. I did find one reference about
this behavior on the following web-page:

https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/listen.3.asp

> An application may call listen() more than once on the same socket.
>   This has the effect of updating the current backlog for the listening
>   socket. Should there be more pending connections than the new backlog
>   value, the excess pending connections are reset and dropped.

It's unclear to me if this also applies to Linux. And so my question is:
what happens when listen is called on the same socket more than once from
the same process? (Apparently there are no visible side-effects in user space,
but does the Linux kernel do something special in kernel space?)

Thanks.

Comment: The [POSIX spec for `listen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/listen.html), as I read it, does not specify the behavior for this case, which means portable code should avoid doing it.

Comment: I wouldn't expect EADDRINUSE. That would happen at the preceding `bind()` step. Maybe EINVAL.

Comment: @zwol: You are right, a portable program should avoid doing it. I was just curious about what does the Linux kernel do.

Comment: @EJP: The behavior or the man page is a bit unclear to me. In my tests calling `bind()` a second time results in an `EINVAL`.  Also, the Linux man page for `listen()` says that one can get `EADDRINUSE` if "another socket is already listening on the same port".

Comment: @userRG That last part about `listen()` is definitely wrong, as it would have already happened at `bind()`. Cut and paste strikes again. Unless `listen()` without `bind()` does an implicit bind? Never heard of that.

Comment: @EJP: Calling `listen()` without bind-ing first is a "valid" sequence. I haven't used this personally but I have seen this being used in some applications. For example, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741061/listen-without-calling-bind

Comment: @userRG In that case the only way you could get EADDRINUSE would be if there were no free TCP ports when you called `listen()`.

Answer (score 2):

The Linux kernel adjusts the backlog queue length using the new backlog value, but only for future connection requests. It does not discard any pending connections already in the queue.

Second and subsequent calls to `listen()` have no other effect, and will not fail unless the socket is of the wrong type (not `SOCK_STREAM`), or is in the wrong state (already connected to a specific peer, or is already in the process of being closed).

Comment: Thanks, @Gil, that seems like the most likely explanation. I'm trying to trace this through the kernel.